# Комбинированные селекторы: передать один в переменной, другой текстом

Tags: jquery

Есть запись

```
$(".box .innerbox").after("<br>");
```

Но вверху, ранее, я уже записал `.box` в переменную

```
var $box = $(".box");
```

Могу ли я использовать эту переменную таким образом

```
$("ЗДЕСЬ ПЕРЕМЕННАЯ .innerbox").after("<br>");
```

Как это правильно сделать чтобы сработало?

Comment: `$($box).find('.innerbox').after("<br>");`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Мне кажется, что этой строчке место в ответе

Comment: Можно обьеденить в селекторную операцию ".box .innerbox>br" или может другая селекторная операция...

Comment: @tutankhamun я не знаю как написать ответ так, чтобы он был пошире, а не просто тупо одна строчка кода. Одинокая строка как-то смешно смотрится. Если хотите - можете это сделать за меня)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Ну подкиньте топикстартеру ссылку на описание метода `find()`. Будет две строчки. Уже ответ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, выбрать селектором в пределах ранее полученного блока можно, в таком виде:

```
var $box = $(".box");
$(".innerbox",$box).after("<br>");
// Равнозначно $(".box .innerbox")...
```

Comment: А в случае `"parent > child"` такой подход можно применить?

Comment: @Plush попробовал. получилось. $(">child",a)

Answer (score 1):

Если следовать инструкции, расположенной в [документации](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85), то можно увидеть, что
в случае, когда некоторые элементы уже найдены, и вам необходимо осуществить поиск элементов внутри них, то удобно воспользоваться методом `find()`.

Т.к. `$box` - элемент, который был уже найден, то именно к нему можно применить данный метод. Причем не обязательно помещать его в скобки как селектор `$($box)`, ведь он же уже выбран (хотя такой подход тоже сработает).

Итого, чтобы выбрать внутренний элемент можно написать:

`$box.find('.innerbox');`

ну и делать все, что душе угодно, в т.ч. вставлять теги:

`$box.find('.innerbox').after("<br>");`

p.s. такой способ сработает тоже: `$($box).find('.innerbox').after("<br>");`, но лучше делать как рекомендуют в доках